# Как сделать PIVOT таблицы с тремя столбцами

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, анализ-данных, pivot

Есть таблица в Pandas:

```
  Название  Значение    дата
0        А        25     5
1        А        15     6
2        А        14     8
3        Б        36     5
4        Б        47     6
5        Б        67     8
6        В        16     6
7        В        95     7
```

Какой функцией его можно быстро перегруппировать, чтобы получилось:

```
    data   А   Б   В
0     5    25  36  Na
1     6    15  47  95
2     7    Na  Na  47
3     8    14  67  Na
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
res = (df
       .pivot(index="дата", columns="Название", values="Значение")
       .rename_axis(None, axis=1)
       .reset_index())
```

---

результат:

```
In [10]: res
Out[10]:
   дата     А     Б     В
0     5  25.0  36.0   NaN
1     6  15.0  47.0  16.0
2     7   NaN   NaN  95.0
3     8  14.0  67.0   NaN
```